# How to obfuscate public IP of Mining pool?

Tags: mining-pools

#### How to obfuscate the public IP address of a mining pool, to protect it against DDOS attacks?

I have a `yiimp` mining pool running on a cloud server.

I would like to secure it with HTTPS and anti-DDOS by obfuscating the public ip using `Cloudflare`, while still retaining stratum mining functionality from the yiimp pool.

The domain of my website is `mycoin.io` and I have set up the DNS to point to cloudflare. So now the website has HTTPs and DDOS protection.

My yiimp pool server is hosted on the cloud at `149.55.55.55` and I have setup cloudflare to redirect subdomain pool.mycoin.io to that ip address.

Now my mining script can look like this:

`-o stratum+tcp://149.55.55.55:3747 -u WALLET_ADDRESS -p c=BUEN`

or like this:

`-o stratum+tcp://pool.mycoin.io:3747 -u WALLET_ADDRESS -p c=BUEN`

But this does not provide any https or anti-ddos protection.

How can I obfuscate the public IP of my pool so that:

`-o stratum+tcp://pool.mycoin.io:3747 -u WALLET_ADDRESS -p c=BUEN`

still works?

Comment: pool.mycoin.io is currently NXDOMAIN - something is not setup right.

Answer (score 1):

The Stratum Mining Protocol ist not based on HTTP, so you will not be able to mediate it through Cloudflare or a similar service, unfortunately. Cloudflare and the like are designed for web content as in web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Use anti-ddos service like cloudflare and it should hide it as well as prevent ddos. I never tried it to mine so not guaranteed ill work but there is no other way to hide it